# python3 tkinter image re-size issue on pi

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi3, image-resizing

Good afternoon,

I am working on doing a live display for my netatmo weather station.  I am successfully interrogating all of the data i need from netatmo and have been displaying it using tkinter in a simple way on my raspberry pi.

I am now trying to add graphics and this is where i have ran into an issue i have not been able to google my way out off.  Essentially what i am doing is laying out my grid with all the different labels/buttons i want then after this trying to resize and image to put it as a background to a button to make the display look a little more attractive.

This is the snippet of code where i am re-sizing the image based on the screen size and number of rows/columns.  does anyone have any ideas why this would work well on Windows but not shrink the image enough on the pi?

```
col_count, row_count = app.grid_size()
for col in range(col_count):
    app.grid_columnconfigure(col, minsize=int(screen_width/col_count))
for row in range(row_count):
    app.grid_rowconfigure(row, minsize=int(screen_height/row_count))

# Now layout is finished resize and add images
im = Image.open('images/Temp_id_basic.png')
im = im.resize((int((screen_width*2)/col_count), int((screen_height*2)/row_count)))
ph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
id_temp_btn.config(image=ph)
```

Comment: we can't run it to see problem so first you could use `print()` to see values in variables and in calculations. Maybe calculations are incorrect and they was good only for screen size in Window.

Comment: Why do you have those `*2`s?  You are explicitly making the images twice as big as will fit in their grid cells.

Comment: Hi, I'll try adding some print statement and see if that reveals anything. A work around for my specific case is to make the image smaller and set it to stretch no ideal as there will be less of quality but the images are only simple. The 2's are because it spans 2 cells. Sean